# My PHP Drupal site sometimes has $_SESSION not set or null

Tags: php, drupal-7, session-state

My Drupal site works fine most of the time.  But when I make many requests per second (using custom code I wrote), the $_SESSION variable is suddenly null or not set.

The error is: Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION

How can this be???

No, I'm not just forgetting the dollar sign.  The code works fine when it's not under load.

Comment: What session storage type are you using

Comment: Drupal stores session data in its database. It also handles the $_SESSION variable.